# What is the most efficient way of counting the number of 1's in an integer?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, numbers, compiler-optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best algorithm to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

Given a 32bit unsigned integer, we want to count the number of non-zero bits in its binary representation. What is the fastest way to do that ?

We want to do this N~10^10 times.

note: using a large look up table is usually not a good idea because of the architecture of current cpu's . it is much faster to calculate it locally than to use a huge array that needs looking at the external memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually several options, I presume the native way is way too slow for this.

You can go with lookup table for 8-bit value and do it in parallel for all four bytes from unsigned int value, then sum the result. This one could be also quite well-paralelizable (be it multi-core, or maybe even some SSE3/4 could help).

You can also go with Brian Kernighan's solution:

```
unsigned int v;              // count the number of bits set in v
unsigned int c;              // c accumulates the total bits set in v
for (c = 0; v; c++)
{
  v &= v - 1;                // clear the least significant bit set
}
```

And the last possible way I found somewhere some time ago is (on 64-bit machines, as the modulo operation would be really fast there):

```
unsigned int v;      // count the number of bits set in v
unsigned int c;      // c accumulates the total bits set in v

c =  ((v & 0xfff) * 0x1001001001001ULL & 0x84210842108421ULL) % 0x1f;
c += (((v & 0xfff000) >> 12) * 0x1001001001001ULL & 0x84210842108421ULL) % 0x1f;
c += ((v >> 24) * 0x1001001001001ULL & 0x84210842108421ULL) % 0x1f;
```